# Not Able to generate the Allure Test Result from simple python and selenium script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, bdd, allure

I am new to allure integration with Python selenium, as a beginner and learning, I want to generate one end test result into an allure report,

Note :
I don't want to use Allure with any of the frameworks like pytest or BDD (Behavior-Driven Development)
Just In my case, i've incorporated Allure into a simple Python script using Selenium without pytest or BDD. But i am getting end result: as follows when u run the following allure command to generate the test result:
cmd: allure generate allure-results --clean
allure-results does not exist
Report successfully generated to allure-report

The prerequisites I am done with are as follows on my Mac:

1. brew install allure
2. pip install allure-pytest

Here is my code`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import allure
import pytest
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
from allure import attachment_type
import os

@allure.feature("Main File")
@allure.description("New Description")
def runscript():
    print("Inside Method")
    chromedriver_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
    service=Service(chromedriver_path)
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    driver.get("https://admin-staging.working.k.zype.com/apps-creator/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    #Set Abosoulute Allure Path:
    allure_resuls_folder_abs_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "allure-results"))
    allure.results_directory(allure_resuls_folder_abs_path)
    name=123
    with allure.step("Checking for error message"):
        if name!=23:
            #allure.attach("Windoe Maximizex", name="Attachment Name", attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.TEXT)
            allure.attach("Window Maximizex", name="Attachment Name", attachment_type=AttachmentType.TEXT)
            assert name  
            print("Debug") 
    print("Debug")

    
    # # Instantiate classes
    # login_operation_obj = loginPage(driver)
    # # brand_creation_obj = BrandSetup(driver)
    # # sponsor_creation_obj= SponsorScreen(driver)


    # # Execute functionalities
    # login_operation_obj.login_page_action()
    # time.sleep(10)
    # brand_creation_obj.brand_creation()   
    # brand_creation_obj.navigate_to_new_brand()
    # time.sleep(10)
    # sponsor_creation_obj.Spon()
    # '''

def main():
    runscript()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

`

Expecting to generate the allure report from my simple python and selenium, but i am not able to generate the result